# How to Connect to hexchat in linux mint 17?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, http-proxy

I have Just installed linux mint 17 on my system. I am operating from behind a http-proxy with authentication. I have manually configured Linux mint to connect via the proxy server and everything else is working fine ( update etc).

But I am not able to connect to hexchat even after correctly configuring the proxy settings.It is throwing the error as-

> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
>    *Proxy traversal failed.
>   * Stopped previous connection attempt (15444)

Anyone having the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that certain ports are blocked by my ISP. The port which I was trying to connect was in the blocked ones.